# Web scraping when multiple clicks are needed

Tags: python, web-scraping

Kindly have a short look here. https://www.cbp.gov/contact/find-broker-by-port/4901. Trying to scrape the list of all brokers, port wise. My question is directed to the approach that needs to be taken when multiple clicks(forward/back) are needed to arrive at a single/multiple data item(s). Could you point me to some reading material on this or any other solution you deem fit. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use selenium for automating multiple clicks (forward/back) as needed, and also  for identifying specific data item.

below you have a very good example.

[1] https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html

Update: Another approach if the website is static is to use requests with beautifulsoup here is an example https://medium.com/@itylergarrett.tag/learning-web-scraping-with-python-requests-beautifulsoup-936e6445312

Comment: I guess you were right. Selenium is the way to go. Thanks.